# CentOS systemd places service subprocesses started with `sudo` in `user.slice` (instead of `system.slice`)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, systemd, cgroups

Subprocesses that are created using `sudo` within a systemd service are placed in the `user.slice`. This behavior has been observed only on CentOS 8 (x86_64 20230606) and not on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, where such subprocesses are placed in the `system.slice` instead.

This is a huge problem because this results in the main service process residing in a different cgroup while the subprocesses created with `sudo` end up in another cgroup. As a result, `systemctl stop` invoked on the service only stops the main service process and not the subprocesses created with `sudo`, so they end up hanging.

Reproduction steps:

1. Login in as a non-root user (that has `sudo` permissions):

```
$ ssh centos@{ADDR}
```

2. Create a bash script `script.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sleep 1000
```

3. Make the script exectuable:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

4. Run the script as a systemd service:

```
$ sudo systemd-run ./script.sh
Running as unit: run-r16ed2fef94d442b5800035653bcbbe01.service
```

5. Check the status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service
● run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service - /home/centos/./script.sh
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-11-15 10:01:49 UTC; 1min 1s ago
 Main PID: 10587 (script.sh)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 97480)
   Memory: 1.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service
           └─10587 /bin/bash /home/centos/./script.sh
```

You can see that neither `sudo` nor `sleep` subprocesses are listed in the resulted cgroup.
Note PID 10587.

6. Check that the sleep processes exist:

```
$ ps aux | grep sleep
root       10588  0.0  0.0 333172  8140 ?        S    10:01   0:00 sudo sleep 1000
root       10591  0.0  0.0 217092   848 ?        S    10:01   0:00 sleep 1000
centos     10687  0.0  0.0 221940  1164 pts/0    S+   10:03   0:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

Stopping the created systemd process will not kill these two `sudo` and `sleep` processes (with PID 10588 and 10591, respectively).

7. Check the systemd slice to which these processes belong:

- The main systemd service process (10587, see `systemctl status` above):

```
$ cat /proc/10587/cgroup | grep name=
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service
```

- The `sudo` subprocess (10588):

```
$ cat /proc/10588/cgroup | grep name=
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-c37.scope
```

- The `sleep` subprocess (10591)"

```
$ cat /proc/10591/cgroup | grep name=
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-c37.scope
```

You can observe that the main script process belongs to the `system.slice`, while the subprocesses belong to the `user.slice`.

In Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with the exact same steps lead to all the subprocesses being placed in the same cgroup, under the `system.slice`:

```
$ sudo systemd-run ./script.sh
Running as unit: run-r09332b0da31a4dd198286a87a917e55f.service
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-92:~$ sudo systemctl status run-r09332b0da31a4dd198286a87a917e55f.service
● run-r09332b0da31a4dd198286a87a917e55f.service - /home/ubuntu/./script.sh
     Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/run-r09332b0da31a4dd198286a87a917e55f.service; transient)
  Transient: yes
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-11-15 10:06:55 UTC; 7s ago
   Main PID: 1729 (script.sh)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18627)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/run-r09332b0da31a4dd198286a87a917e55f.service
             ├─1729 /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/./script.sh
             ├─1730 sudo sleep 1000
             └─1731 sleep 1000
```

So stopping this service kills all the subprocesses.

So what is going on in CentOS? How can I make systemd there to behave the same way it does in Ubuntu? Can I force the subprocesses to be placed in the same cgroup under `system.slice`?

I checked the systemd parameters for the created service in CentOS and they are effectively identical to Ubuntu's. In particular, the `Slice` parameter is set in CentOS to `system.slice`:

```
$ sudo systemctl show run-rf4fe2865d42240c1a95f1ed497575494.service | grep Slice=
Slice=system.slice
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Exchnage !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systemd service configuration does not take over child process creation nor move child process anywhere. That's done by the PAM configuration of `sudo` itself, which unnecessarily invokes `pam_systemd` (perhaps deliberately to achieve the result that you don't want, or perhaps just in an attempt to have XDG_RUNTIME_DIR set for the target user when people try to run GUI apps as root? I don't know).

The PAM module creates a systemd-logind session and this causes logind to move the invoking process to the "session" cgroup, in much the same way that your own shell process gets moved out of sshd.service or getty@.service when you log in.

Edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` to disable the use of this module. Take care to not disable it for other PAM configurations, however – if the file includes /etc/pam.d/system-auth (which is also used by console and SSH logins), you'll want to keep pam_systemd there; instead you might have to insert a [pam_succeed_if](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/pam/pam_succeed_if.8.en) to trick PAM into skipping it:

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service = sudo
session whatever                   pam_systemd.so
```

("success=1" skips 1 next module if pam_succeed_if returns PAM_SUCCESS, while "default=ignore" causes all other results to be disregarded.)

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! This was exactly it. I had this line in my `/etc/pam.d/sudo`: `session    include      system-auth` (I assume that is the one related to `pam_systemd`).

I removed it and now systemd spawns all the subprocesses started with `sudo` in the same cgroup and all of them are now killed during `systemctl stop`! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `session include system-auth` imports whatever 'session' modules exist in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. That's probably where pam_systemd is enabled (although it shouldn't be, but I suppose CentOS arranges the PAM includes differently).

Comment: Ah yes, there is this line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`: `-session    optional                                     pam_systemd.so`. I will try removing just that and will keep `session    include      system-auth` in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and will see if that works. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Well, the way it's arranged it probably won't be a good idea to just edit system-auth, as SSH uses the same configuration – and you *do* want SSH logins to be moved out of sshd.service – so it might be necessary to keep system-auth as is but copy its contents directly into pam.d/sudo (minus systemd)...

Comment: Or alternatively you could insert a pam_succeed_if to have PAM itself skip over the next 1 module if 'service = sudo'... (That is, `session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service = sudo` if I remember the syntax right.)

Comment: Ok, I see. I will keep system-auth untouched then and will try somehow skipping pam_systemd (or copy paste the entries from system-auth to pam.d/sudo (without the pam_systemd) in the worst case, that is also acceptable for me). Thanks!